# 403 Error when running perl script in apache

Tags: linux, apache, perl, ubuntu, cgi

I am trying to test perl scripts through localhost. I configured apache to allow perl scripts to be run from /usr/lib/cgi-bin (or so I thought). Whenever I go to localhost/cgi-bin/script.pl I get a 403 Forbidden error. Here is my apache conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/cgtopher/public_html/

<Directory /home/cgtopher/public_html/>
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>

#cgi-bin

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">

AllowOverride None

Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks

Order allow,deny

Require all granted

</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/cgtopher/.apache/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

In my error log I keep getting this:

```
[Sat Sep 05 10:30:12.565510 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 10918] [client 127.0.0.1:60699] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.pl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Order allow,deny`, which will reject the request unless *at least* one Allow directive passes.

You have no Allow directive (except for Directory /home/cgtopher/public_html/, which does not cover the cgi-bin directory).

(Add `Allow from all` to the cgi-bin directory?)

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks like it worked, with one caveat. Instead of the script running (just a hello world for testing) I'm getting prompted to download it. So we're halfway there!

Comment: That's odd.  ScriptAlias should set the handler.  Are you sure it's the script that's being downloaded, and not its output?